# n:m relation with many records that are just 1m correctly approach

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I've a table of USERS in mysql that is in relation m:n with a CITY table.

User are 3 types identified by a field TYPE: regular, admin, super.

The regular user could be linked at maximum with 1 city.
The admin user could be linked at max just with 1 city.
The Super user is linked with all cities.

Is correct to store all 3 types of user in just one table and having n:m that for most user is just 1:m and just the SUPER USER is a pure n:m. is that the correct approach?

Comment: Users table is list of users, and `type` is just a column in that table?

Comment: yes @D.Kasipovic thats correct

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think you need separate relational table (even if it is mostly good idea for future improvements, should you decide that user needs to connect to more than 1 city).

What I would do instead, is create `city_id` column in users table, and fill it accordingly. I am saying this because of the SUPER USERSs, as you call them. If you create separate relational table, it will have `(number of super users) * (number of cities)` entries, and since super user can see all cities, you would need to add `(number of cities)` rows to the table, each time you create a new user. Also, each time you create a new city, you would need to add `(number of super users)` rows to the relational table.

Instead, as I said, I would just use `city_id` in the users table, and if the user if `super user` then he sees all cities, and if not, only the city from `city_id` column.

This is just my personal preference.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: correct me if im wrong: -the SUPERUSER is just one so will be-->1*(numb.of cyties) -if im putting a city_id on user table i will in 1:m case, so will be hard to model the super user skill to see every city or i wrong?

Comment: You are correct about the number of rows if you have one super user, but basically what you will get in relational table is just a copy of all city_id from the city table. Once again, relational tables are a good practice, but for your second question (difficulty of implementation), it really depends on what you plan to do with that data later, how did you model your software, etc. I was just giving you one point of view, which can be wrong of course, or totally unsuited to your needs.

Comment: your comment and point of view is very wellcome to me! Im asking just for improve my knowledge and looks to different approach style! im think to go for the m:m with limitation, putting an user_id on the city table is not right to me, and having all the cities linked with one user so is not possible with USER 1:m CITIES or i wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is not possible when joining tables (at least not in a pretty way, per say), that is why I said it largely depends on your software, which is connecting to the database, and how you parse data afterwards.